# Is "petrol head" used for people who love vehicles?

Tags: british-english

I have heard people saying **petrol head** for people who love vehicles. Is it actually correct ?

Also, what word is there for **people who love watches**?

Comment: loves watches? do you mean loves vehicles?

Comment: Both. A person who loves watches ? what do you call him/her ? AND
A person who loves vehicles ? what do you call him/her ?

Comment: How about a _____ freak/maniac/fan/enthusiast/person/man...

Comment: @DullaDeCozta: In the U.S., for a person (in the stereotype, a young male) who is obsessed with automobiles, a common term is "GearHead." The term for one who enjoys collecting watches is "A person of wealth, culture and discernment."

Comment: @P.E.Dant... at least those are the terms that the watch salesman uses when he is speaking to somebody like that.

Comment: @JavaLatte True perhaps of Timex or Tissot; Patek de Genève have no need of sales personnel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems *petrol head* is popular enough to have its own entry at Urban Dictionary. So there is evidence of its existence.

> [petrol head](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=petrolhead&utm_source=search-action)
>    Enthusiast of petrol (gasoline) engines or cars

Cambridge Dictionary also lists

> [petrolhead](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/petrolhead)
>   /ˈpet.rəlˌhed/ UK informal
>   someone who likes and uses their car a lot, and does not want to use any other type of transport

In the US, you might hear *motorhead*, or *gearhead*.

> 1. [gearhead](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gearhead)
>      Someone who is totally into cars and is very knowledgeable about how to modify and fix them.
> 2. [motorhead](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Motorhead)
>      A motor vehicle or motorcycle enthusiast. An enthusiast for working on motor vehicles.

As for watches, you might consider

> [horophile](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horophile)
>   a person who has an obsession with timekeeping devices

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the terms suggested by @Max

For cars:

> pistonhead

as in [pistonheads.com](http://www.pistonheads.com)

For watches:

> [horophiliac](http://tofo.me/tag/horophiliac)